# JavaScript reduce with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a piece of code that just works.
This code looks for the largest value in the array of numbers.
Could someone translate this to simple JavaScript(without ternary) so a novice programmer can understand it?

```
  const mostVotes = votes.reduce((bestIndex, v, i, arr) => v > arr[bestIndex] ? i : bestIndex, 0);
```

At first, I was trying to implement Math.max, but I needed the index of the largest value in the array, so I went after reduce and
this is what I was trying to do with it.

```
const mostVotes = votes.reduce((acc, value, i, arr) => {
  if(value > acc) {
    return i
  }
}, 0)
```

Thanks for the answers, much appreciated! I'm starting to understand this and it's much clearer now. Javascript reduce and ternary together is a nice fit.

Comment: *I tried to translate it myself, but that code didn't work.* — you should post that code.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator. And that *wasn't* the edit that @Pointy suggested...

Comment: Removed that part.

Comment: You could see a ternary operator is just a simple version of an if else statement. It's not complicated. You can learn that easily.

Comment: `?` means the condition is truthy, `:` means the condition is falsy. condition `?` (it's truthy) `:` (it's falsy).

Comment: `if (v > arr[bestIndex]) { return i } else { return bestIndex }`

Comment: If you would have shown what you have tried instead of removing the `I tried to translate it myself, but that code didn't work.` then we would have been able to tell you what your misunderstanding about that expression was.

Comment: Again: Show that translated version that did not work. There is probably just a little missunderstanding, and it is impossible to say what it is without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the code you provided is looping through each element in `votes` and checking whether it is greater than an element stored at a particular index. This index is stored in the variable `bestIndex` an is used to mark/keep track of the index which holds the largest element from all elements seen while looping.

In your example, your ternary is checking if a given element is larger than the currently marked biggest element (by doing `v > arr[bestIndex]`). If this is the case we then set the index of the current element to be the new position of the largest element (by implicitly returning `i`). If this is not the case, we leave the index of the largest element as it is by implicitly returning `bestIndex`.

You can translate this into a more procedural style of programming by using for loops and if-statements like so:

```js
let votes = [-4, 10, 100, -3, 40];

let positionOfMax = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
  if(votes[i] > votes[positionOfMax]) {  // v > arr[bestIndex]
    positionOfMax = i; // ? i (from ternary)
  }
  /* Not needed
    else {posittionOfMax = positionOfMax} // : bestIndex (from ternary)
  */
}
console.log(positionOfMax);
```

I encourage you to take a look at [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the documentation on the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). They're both useful and powerful tools which can help speed up your development.

Answer (score -1):

What might be confusing about the original code was the lack of brackets `{}`.

`() => 'test'` is the same as `() => { return 'test' }`

In your case:

```
(bestIndex, v, i, arr) => v > arr[bestIndex] ? i : bestIndex

(bestIndex, v, i, arr) => {
  return (v > arr[bestIndex] ? i : bestIndex)
}

(bestIndex, v, i, arr) => {
  if(v > arr[bestIndex])
    return i
  else 
    return bestIndex
}

const mostVotes = votes.reduce((bestIndex, v, i, arr) => {
  if(v > arr[bestIndex])
    return i
  else 
    return bestIndex
}, 0);
```

Comment: That first sentence is really a comment, not an answer. And even if you would remove that, the OP is asking for *an explanation* yet you haven't given one.

Comment: Well, he's only asking for a 'translation' that he can understand and I've provided a step-by-step 'translation'. I think he'd be able to understand it but I get what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

The below `if/else` should get you to where you want to be.

```
if (v > arr[bestIndex]) {
  return i
} else {
  return bestIndex
}
```

Comment: Because the part before the `? ` in `v > arr[bestIndex] ? i : bestIndex` is `v > arr[bestIndex]` and not `arr[bestIndex]`. You condition is if `arr[bestIndex]` is truthy, but the original code is about `v` beeing larger then `arr[bestIndex]`